# Specify return type of a wrapper function that calls an abstract method in Python

Tags: python, object, abstract-class, type-hinting

For this example, consider the simplified scenario where a `Solver` will return a `Solution`.

We have `Solution`s:

```py
class Solution(ABC):
    pass


class AnalyticalSolution(Solution):
    pass


class NumericalSolution(Solution):
    def get_mesh_size(self) -> float:
        return 0.12345
```

And `Solver`s:

```py
class Solver(ABC):
    def solve(self, task: int) -> Solution:
        # Do some pre-processing with task
        # ...
        return self._solve(task)

    @abstractmethod
    def _solve(self, task: int) -> Solution:
        pass


class NumericalSolver(Solver):
    def _solve(self, task: int) -> NumericalSolution:
        return NumericalSolution()


class AnalyticalSolver(Solver):
    def _solve(self, task: int) -> AnalyticalSolution:
        return AnalyticalSolution()
```

The problem I encounter results from the implementation of the wrapper method `solve` that then calls the abstract method `_solve`.
I often encounter a situation like this where I want to do some preprocessing in the `solve` method that is the same for all solver, but then the actual implementation of `_solve` might differ.

If I now call the numerical solver and call the `get_mesh_size()` method, Pylance (correctly) tells me that a `Solution` object has no `get_mesh_size`member.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    solver = NumericalSolver()
    solution = solver.solve(1)
    print(solution.get_mesh_size())
```

I understand that Pylance only sees the interface of `solve` which indicates that the return type is a `Solution` object that does not need to have a `get_mesh_size` method.
I am also aware that this example works at runtime.

I tried to use `TypeVar` like this (actually, because ChatGPT suggested it):

```py
class Solution(ABC):
    pass
T = TypeVar("T", bound=Solution)
```

and then rewrite the `Solver` class:

```py
class Solver(ABC):
    def solve(self, task: int) -> T:
        # Do some pre-processing with task
        # ...
        return self._solve(task)

    @abstractmethod
    def _solve(self, task: int) -> T:
        pass
```

But Pylance now tells me `TypeVar "T" appears only once in generic function signature`. So this can't be the solution.

**How do I get typing to work with this example?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `Generic[T]` as a base for `Solver` and then extend it as follows

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import TypeVar, Generic


class Solution(ABC):
    pass


class AnalyticalSolution(Solution):
    pass


class NumericalSolution(Solution):
    def get_mesh_size(self) -> float:
        return 0.12345


SolutionGeneric = TypeVar("SolutionGeneric", bound=Solution)


class Solver(ABC, Generic[SolutionGeneric]):
    def solve(self, task: int) -> SolutionGeneric:
        # Do some pre-processing with task
        # ...
        return self._solve(task)

    @abstractmethod
    def _solve(self, task: int) -> SolutionGeneric:
        pass


class NumericalSolver(Solver[NumericalSolution]):
    def _solve(self, task: int) -> NumericalSolution:
        return NumericalSolution()


class AnalyticalSolver(Solver):
    def _solve(self, task: int) -> AnalyticalSolution:
        return AnalyticalSolution()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    solver = NumericalSolver()
    solution = solver.solve(1)
    print(solution.get_mesh_size())
```